# Why isn't the callback within Promise deferred to be run?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-6

Following is a demo:

```
var forever = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  while (true) {
  }
  resolve("done")

});
console.log("Promise returned")
```

The `console.log("Promise returned")` will never be executed. It seems that the evaluate of `forever` will block the thread and never return.

Wrap the function body into a `setTimeout` fixed this issue:

```
var forever = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    while (true) {
    }
    resolve("done")
  },0)

});
console.log("Promise returned")
```

Shouldn't the callback parameter of `Promise` be **deferred** to be execute (no need to be wrapped by setTimeout)? Is there any documentation about this behavior?

Comment: No. If you wrap a function that makes an ajax call in a Promise, is it going to defer making the call over the network?

Comment: No, there's no reason to defer the executor. Yes, this is documented; I'll search for the dupe. The lesson is that you should not put infinite loops in your code.

Comment: What's the point of this code? Creating a promise that never resolves can  be done *a lot* easier.

Answer (score 3):

[Section 25.4.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-executor) of the spec states that "when the Promise function is called with argument executor" the following steps are taken:

> 9. Let completion be `Call(executor, undefined, «resolvingFunctions.[[Resolve]], resolvingFunctions.[[Reject]]»)`.

Thus, the spec requires that the callback to a `Promise` constructor be called during construction. [MDN notes thi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s as well:

> The executor function is executed immediately.

The `executor` function does not necessarily need to call `resolve` or `reject` immediately, but is itself called before `new Promise` returns.

Answer (score 0):

The function passed to `new Promise()` is called synchronously.  It may call other async functions, and resolve (or reject) the promise within the callbacks of those functions, but if you do `while (true)` directly within that top-level function it *will* immediately block the browser.

Comment: `while(true){}` will always block the browser, regardless when you execute it :-)

Comment: @Bergi fair point - now qualified :)